# How does Tarmogoyf interact with changelings?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What would happen if you had a [Mirror Entity](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mirror%20Entity) (or any card with changeling) in your graveyard and a [Tarmogoyf](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tarmogoyf) in play? Would Tarmogoyf's ability only count Mirror Entity as a shapeshifter type creature or a changeling type (every type)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing special would happen, because Tarmogoyf doesn't care about the Changeling ability at all, or anything Mirror Entity does. Unless it's in a graveyard, in which case Tarmogoyf sees there's a Creature card in the graveyard, and becomes at least a 1/2 from that.

[Tarmogoyf](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tarmogoyf)'s ability reads:

> Tarmogoyf's power is equal to the number of **card types** among cards in all graveyards and its toughness is equal to that number plus 1.

The card types are clarified in a ruling on Tarmogoyf you can see in Gatherer:

> The card types that can appear on cards in a graveyard are artifact, creature, enchantment, instant, land, planeswalker, sorcery, and tribal.

... which means Tarmogoyf's ability can make it an 8/9 at most. For {1}{G}, that's still a pretty big deal. (That clarification also shows up in the reminder text of [Tarmogoyf's original Future Sight printing](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=136142).)

Simply put, it doesn't care about creature types, or the *changeling* ability. Creature cards don't count as "card types", they are [subtypes](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Subtype) — the part after the dash in the type line — and Tarmogoyf doesn't pay any attention to those at all. Every creature card just counts for one type: *Creature*. (Unless, y'know, they're an *Enchantment Creature* or *Artifact Creature* or they're [Dryad Arbor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dryad%20Arbor), in which case they count for two types.) Also, Tarmogoyf only cares about cards in graveyards, while Mirror Entity's ability only affects creature permanents on the battlefield.

Comment: _"Mirror Entity's ability only affects creature permanents on the battlefield"_ - except itself, Changeling works everywhere. Not that it changes anything here.